# How to create an annotaded bibliography for unsrt bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies

How can I make an annotated bibliography using the unsrt style? I use the unsrt biliography style to create the reference list based on the order the references appear in the document.

I use a bibtex file that holds all the entries of my bibliography. I want to add an extra field to each entry with a short description which should then appear in the bibliography.

Current code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\title{The current state of cross-platform game development for different device     types}
\author{...}
\date{...}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\input{Preface.tex}
\input{Abstract.tex}
....
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

example entry of bibtex file:

```
@inproceedings{someref,
 author = {....},
 title = {....},
 ....
 publisher = {....},
 AnnotationOrSomething = {blabla}
}
```

I use sharelatex as editor.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you considered using the `note` field for the annotations? Separately, have you considered using the style `unsrtnat` instead of `unsrt`? Two advantages of `unsrtnat` are (i) good interface with the `natbib` package and (ii) recognition by default of field such as `url`, `eid`, and `isbn`.

Comment: You also can use `biblatex`, which uses the `numeric` style by default and is relatively easy to customise. Its `addendum` field is like the `note` field, but is printed at the end of the entry.

Comment: I didn't know about the note field. That's enough for what I need. Thanks!